# How to get LinkedIn company follower using API on Monarch plugin for Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api

Recently there were some changes in Monarch Plugin to get the follower count from LinkedIn. Monarch plugin only helps to get you the follower from your profile. What to do when you need your company follower count using LinkedIn API in Monarch plugin. I have made few changes. This is monarch plugin_version = '1.2.3':
First we have to change in monarch.php  file

```
case 'linkedin' :
if ( isset( $settings['access_tokens']['linkedin'] ) ) {
    $url = sprintf( 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(num-connections)?oauth2_access_token=%1$s&format=json', $settings['access_tokens']['linkedin'] );
}
```

make some change as below TO get company follower count

```
case 'linkedin' :
if ( isset( $settings['access_tokens']['linkedin'] ) ) {
    $url = sprintf( 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{company_id}/num-followers?oauth2_access_token=%1$s&format=json', $settings['access_tokens']['linkedin'] );
}
```

Then second change in the same file

```
case 'linkedin':
    $authorization_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&**scope=r_basicprofile**&state=%1$s&client_id=%2$s&redirect_uri=%3$s';
```

I change above code to

```
case 'linkedin':
    $authorization_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&state=%1$s&client_id=%2$s&redirect_uri=%3$s';
```